# [no]foldenable / foldmethod for each buffer but keep those settings persist for each buffer

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I have two opening buffers and one has `foldenable` and `foldmethod=indent`, other has `nofoldenable` and `foldmethod=syntax`.

I need that when I move between buffers, each buffer has it own `fold` settings and for example a buffer keeps folded even I move to other buffer that has `nofoldenable`

Can we achieve this?

Vim 8.1 / Archlinux

Answer (score 2):

If by move between buffers you mean -- doing it with a single window (no splits) then the only(?) option is to use autocommands. As an example:

```
augroup fold_params | au!
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py :setl fdm=indent | setl foldenable
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.c :setl fdm=syntax | setl nofoldenable
augroup end
```

Options `foldmethod` and `foldenable` are local to window so you have to redefine them as soon as you open other file/buffer in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by set `setlocal` for `python` file and `nofoldenable` in global in `.vimrc`.